# Dell PowerEdge Server - What is a Maser Daughter Card?

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

In the inventory of the components of the Dell PowerEdge server that we are wanting to procure, i see the following :-

Maser Daughter Card - Quantity 1

Maser SW  - Quantity 1 - Am assuming this entry is for some software for the above.

Can anyone help me with the following?

1. What is a Maser Daughter card?
2. What is it use in a server?

[image]

Comment: I can't find any reference to this anywhere other than in reference to this question or the similar one you placed on Dell's support forum. Could you show us where this is on their site - a link perhaps?

Comment: Actually, i didnt post anything in Dell's forum but i too did see a similar question there - with no answers. I have got a quotation from Dell Sales Manager with this entry for this very strange component :-)

Comment: Have you asked this sales manager????

Comment: Yes :-) She doesnt have a clue either. She said she will contact her technical guys and get back. Am waiting for her to get back still so thought i might ask as others on the forum might be aware in case it is something standard in Dell servers

Comment: Its gotta be a typo of  'master' but then that begs the question of what a 'master daughter card' does...

Comment: @Farseeker - thanks for the edit. I was wondering what i had to do to get the picture embedded. BTW, a Master Daughter card really sounds like a oxymoron but hell what do i know!!

Comment: Well, a daughter-board is something that's often found in Dell Blades, so I guess a "Master" daughter-board might be a daughter-board that's a master for a slave board? I dunno I'm grasping at straws here!

Comment: @Farseeker - Even the Dell chaps (atleast the one i am talking with) seems to be completely clueless about this card or what it is for. This is not a blade server though but your point about daughter board gives me something to atleast check with him about. Thanks!

Comment: @All - Farseeker's comments were the one that made most sense. No further inputs available from Dell Sales on this one either. Closing this thread with a +1 helpful for Farseekers comment.

Comment: They'd better not be putting MASERs in our servers! 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maser

Answer (score 1):

I asked our Dell account manger this after seeing it on an M910 blade. Apparently it's just an internal factory code that is used for distribution, and doesn't mean anything to an end user.

Comment: thanks for that update. The Dell guy at my end didnt have a clue :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a code name for Dell's proprietary embedded management also called Lifecycle controller, it helps with OS deployment with the latest drivers, installing updates, monitoring and performing maintenance on the system when the OS is not present.